# TensorFlow - Training accuracy not improving in MNIST data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist, kaggle

I write a program with tensorflow to process Kaggle's digit-recognizer problem.Program can run normally,but the training accuracy is always low,about 10%,such as following :

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.11
step 100, training accuracy 0.13
step 200, training accuracy 0.21
step 300, training accuracy 0.12
step 400, training accuracy 0.07
step 500, training accuracy 0.08
step 600, training accuracy 0.15
step 700, training accuracy 0.05
step 800, training accuracy 0.08
step 900, training accuracy 0.12
step 1000, training accuracy 0.05
step 1100, training accuracy 0.09
step 1200, training accuracy 0.12
step 1300, training accuracy 0.1
step 1400, training accuracy 0.08
step 1500, training accuracy 0.11
step 1600, training accuracy 0.17
step 1700, training accuracy 0.13
step 1800, training accuracy 0.11
step 1900, training accuracy 0.13
step 2000, training accuracy 0.07
……
```

Following is my code:

```python
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, w):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    # ksize = [batch, heigh, width, channels], strides=[batch, stride, stride, channels]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])      
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])      
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

x_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])

w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])    
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])    
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

w_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])   
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])     
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)
# dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)      
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
# softmax
w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(10e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

def get_batch(i, size, train, label):
    startIndex = (i * size) % 42000
    endIndex = startIndex + size
    batch_X = train[startIndex : endIndex]
    batch_Y = label[startIndex : endIndex]
    return batch_X, batch_Y


data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train_data = data.drop(['label'], axis=1)
train_data = train_data.values.astype(dtype=np.float32)
train_data = train_data.reshape(42000, 28, 28, 1)

label_data = data['label'].tolist()
label_data = tf.one_hot(label_data, depth=10)
label_data = tf.Session().run(label_data).astype(dtype=np.float64)


batch_size = 100                             
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for i in range(20000):   
    batch_x, batch_y = get_batch(i, batch_size, train_data, label_data)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x_image: batch_x, y_: batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x_image: batch_x, y_: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.9})
```

I don't know what's wrong with my program.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your `bias_variable` function - not sure how a `tf.Variable(tf.constant)` behaves, plus that we usually initialise biases at zero, not 0.1:

```python
def bias_variable(shape):
    return tf.zeros((shape), dtype = tf.float32)
```

If this doesn't help, try initializing your weights with `stddev=0.01`

Comment: Thanks your answer very much! I change weights and bias's stddev to 0.01,the program is run normally before about step 3000, accuracy is about 0.99.However, after step 3000, accuracy become about 0.1 suddenly.It's strange very much.

Comment: @Lixudong this is another, different question - kindly accept this answer and open a new post